# What values can/should be used for the isentropic efficiency of a compressor and turbine?

Tags: efficiency, turbine, compressor

I was trying to model an turbofan aircraft engine using Matlab and Simulink. In the process I have fixed certain parameters to some specific values which are nominal operating values of the parameters. Can anyone please help me out with the values of isentropic efficiencies of compressor and turbine used in the above case?

Comment: I'm no aircraft designer, but when you say "used in the above case", I'm not seeing a use case with enough details to get a good answer. Maybe you've provided everything needed, but I'm going to bet more details are necessary.

Comment: Related: [What is the efficiency of the turbine of a modern jet engine?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/55748/14897)

Comment: Unless you want to model a specific engine, standard numbers are given in the book 'Mechanics and Thermodynamics of Propulsion'. You can find it online. Or, you can look at this site https://www.particleincell.com/2014/turbofan-calculator/

Comment: Thank you, will look into tat

Answer (score 1):

An answer is in the table of the linked question: [What is the efficiency of the turbine of a modern jet engine?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/55748/what-is-the-efficiency-of-the-turbine-of-a-modern-jet-engine). Column 4 is for modern engines, column 1 is for old engines, about 1960’s technology. So, take your pick. In order to get a simulation running, an exactly correct figure isn’t necessary, something in the ball-park is fine.

The third comment above gives another similar source. Either would be fine.

Comment: Thank you, will look into that